# Unity Build GPU Performance

Tags: unity, performance, gpu, nvidia

I have been banging my head against the wall with this for few days now with no improvement..

The problem is that after build my project keeps using over 30% of the GPU. Even in the editor it takes 20%+
I ended up making a new empty scene with few cubes with rigidbodies, but the performance was still going over 30%. It starts with 3-5 % and within the next 5-10 seconds starts climbing up.

I am using Unity 2019.1.12f1, but the problem is still there even on the newest Unity 2020 version.
The project is using LWRP.

I have played around with the quality settings but they seem to have absolutely no effect on the issue, besides turning the V-Sync on, which capped the framerate at acceptable levels.

I am using Windows 10 , my video card is Geforce GTX 1080 Ti.

Here are some screenshots + the project build

Project: https://easyupload.io/foqq5x

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have vsync On?

Comment: @Vaillancourt From what I understood the only way to turn on vsync in Unity is to set the VSync Count to some value. I have it on Every Vbank as it is shown on the screenshot. Before that the build was running on 1000 + FPS and the CPU and GPU were on 100%

Comment: Ah, right, looks like I read your question too fast.

Comment: Have you checked if Unity is baking a lightmap in the background?

Comment: @user3797758 In the new scene that I created with the cubes that option was turned on. Still though that shouldnt affect the build version. I tested it now, by clearing all baked data, disabling the auto lightmap baking option and making a new build. It had no effect. Yesterday I even removed all lights from the scene and it still had no effect.

Comment: It can affect the build if you build in a location that doesn't have lightmap data cached, cause it has to regenerate all the data from scratch (but yeah not in your case). Have you looked updated graphics drivers? Also if using the render pipelines it might have it's own set of quality settings rather than using the project settings...

Comment: @user3797758  Yeah I updated to latest Nvidia drivers. As for the render settings, you were right, I had forgotten to check those settings. I made new project and literally disabled everything in quality settings and the LWRP settings, removed all lights and shadows. The result was pretty much the same... sometimes it climbed to 20% and other times back to 30% GPU or more. I am really getting frustrated with this thing... How does an empty LWRP project perform for you ?

Comment: I made a "Universal template" project and opened the pre-made construction sample scene without changing any setting, it thinks about GI for a min and then CPU goes to 0.9% and GPU to 0%, in play mode its more like 28% CPU and 35% GPU. This is with Unity 2020.1.4f1 and a less powerful GPU.

Comment: @user3797758 Thanks allot! Hmm interesting so you are getting pretty much the same results. Maybe Unity just takes a percentage of the available GPU/CPU regardless if it actually needs it or not. Can you please try building that project and see how it performs then ? There is a difference between playing it in the editor and in the already build project.

Comment: I'm a bit confused I thought you were annoyed that Unity was using to many resources in play mode? but that comment makes me think you want it to use 100%?

Comment: No no you were right the first time, I dont want it to use so much resources. Maybe we arent on the same page when talking about play mode. I thought that play mode was when you are in Unity and you just press the play button. And my main concern is that after you build your project and start it then the application that Unity just build/created is taking too much resources. I have noticed that there is about 10%  GPU difference between those two. (atleast for me)

Comment: Play mode is when you are in the Unity Editor and press the play button and see the project running inside the "Game" tab, correct :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing are various bottlenecks when performance isn't purposely limited.

If you run a game (even a static none-moving cube) a typical game engine will tell the GPU to render and then go through the game loop and tell the GPU to render again. If there is nothing going on in the game this is very fast the GPU spends most of it's time doing a bit of rendering and then spends the rest of the time sending that data to the display and waiting. The cycle repeats and the game might run at a few thousand FPS and look static while using 100% of the resources of the computer, this is normal.

In that scenario you have told the game engine to go crazy and draw as many frames of the same cube as possible, it'll go and do that but certain parts of the rendering process take longer and cause the GPU to wait, like when it has finished and needs new work (but the CPU is busy doing other stuff) so it'll sit there idle waiting for the next draw calls to be sent. You can change the balance a little if you change render resolution which will mean the GPU has to spend more/less time calculating pixel values, accordingly the perceived GPU utilisation will change.

All of this happens when you tell the game to go as fast as possible! If you instead know "I want 60 FPS" you can tell the game to try it's best to make every frame take 16ms and that means that the GPU/CPU will sit idle more (assuming that you where managing more than 60 FPS before) and task manager will tell you it's being used less.

[image: performance sample]

So in this picture you can see that it takes roughly the same amount of time to render either way if you have v-sync on or off but the CPU will wait on purpose until the current frame has taken enough time in order to hit a performance target which forces the PC to be idle lowering the resources used.

### Things to note

The problem with empty games or static scenes are that if nothing has moved technically nothing needs to be re-rendered but working this out is too slow for modern games where 99% of the time something is happening. If you know that nothing is going to happen (like when you are in a menu or something like that) you can build ways of caching the previous frame and re-render it but that's out of scope for this question. So if you know nothing has changed and you see the GPU doing stuff you might get the impression that the game engine is wasting resources and depending on your point of view it might be but if you where to 'optimise' a standard game engine for that use case it will cost you more performance when you need it once you actually start making stuff move on screen and the calculation tells you not to cache the frame most of the time.

Some game engines will look at the last few frames and notice trends and optimise the game on the fly to get more performance which can change the CPU to GPU load ratio. Unity's Entity system is one case where it takes a few frames to "Warn up" until it knows what requests the game will make and how it needs to structure the data in memory in order minimise overhead (though Unity being Unity this will probably be different in a few years when they inevitably change the system).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically you mean those resources aren't actually used, the GPU is just waiting for something to happen. 
As for my original project it used around 10% more GPU than the empty scene. Does that mean those resources are still not used or I have to optimize my game graphics to take less resources? For example I ran Subnautica which is also done with Unity and the GPU load was the same as for my empty scene. Does that mean their game is optimized really well? Also do you know how can I track the performance load besides the task manager, just the Unity Profiler ?

Comment: Without looking at your project in depth I don't know what your doing that uses resources. There are millions of variables that you could track in one game vs another, I'd look around at what over people have done to increase performance. As for tracking it long term, make performance benchmarks and setup an automated environment to run it every time you add to source control, then you can look at graphs and see the difference over time https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/09/25/performance-benchmarking-in-unity-how-to-get-started/